# Log likelihood function estimation for discrete random effect

Tags: random-effects-model, likelihood

I have a likelihood function that is:

$L(\theta)=\prod_{i=1}^I (\psi_1 L_i(\theta|\mu_1)+\psi_2 L_i(\theta|\mu_2))$

where $\theta, \mu_1, \mu2, \psi_1, \psi_2$ are parameters to be estimated.

So, this is like, there are two groups(1 and 2) who share the same unobserved heterogeneity parameter $\mu_1, \mu_2$, and each individual contributes to the likelihood as a weighted likelihood:

$L_i(\theta|\mu_k)$, $k=1,2$ with associated probability weight $\psi_k$ (sum up to one).

But how can I take log of $L(\theta)$? Any idea of transformation?

Thank you.

+) If I just take log,
$\ln L(\theta)=\sum_{i=1}^I \ln(\psi_1 L_i(\theta|\mu_1)+\psi_2 L_i(\theta|\mu_2))$, right?

Is there any way that I could make use of $\ln L_i(\theta|\mu_k)$?
My $L_i(\theta|\mu_k)$ is in form of multiplication of independent prababilities. It would be great to make it linear for the optimization purpose.

Comment: What’s going wrong in taking the log?

Comment: You just take the log. It will become the sum of log

Comment: Is $\psi_2=1-\psi_1$?

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, they sum up to 1.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Can I somehow use log of individual contribution, $\ln L_i(\theta|\mu_k)$?

Comment: You cannot linearize this mixture model. You *should* be working with the $\log(L_i(\theta\mid\mu_j)$ and you *ought* to parameterize the $\psi_j$ in terms of their logits.  That will permit reliable computation of the log likelihood without underflows.  (It's unclear why you use subscripts $L_i$ in the formula, though: that implies you are assuming a different (but known) probability law for each observation.)